# Test pdf content using C# in acceptance tests

Tags: c#, acceptance-testing, pdftron

I am trying to test pdf content which is stored in blob in my acceptance tests, I am using c# and pdftron library

I am able to fetch the content but there were some special characters included in content in place of some characters and those are not consistent as well

I tried with ITextsharp as well and facing the same issue

Is there any better way to implement this

Comment: If the issue is file specific, it might be best to open a ticket with the support team at Apryse (support.apryse.com).